# how to set env variables on a per screen name basis

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-screen

I use multiple screens on my system, I'm using separate session for each branch I may be working on. Now I would like to set environment variables depending on screen name (I name screens by branch path). I've tried this in `~/.screenrc`:

```
screen -t "ABC-1234" bash -ic 'OUTPUTROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/ABC-1234/bin'
screen -t "ABC-1234" bash -ic 'SVN_ROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/ABC-1234'
screen -t "DEF-5678" bash -ic 'OUTPUTROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/DEF-5678/bin'
screen -t "DEF-5678" bash -ic 'SVN_ROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/DEF-5678'
```

but it doesn't seem to work, the env variables do not get set if my screens are called "ABC-1234" or "DEF-5678" and I open a new window using `Ctrl-a c` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start your screens from a shellscript:

```
#!/bin/sh
SVN_ROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/ABC-1234 OUTPUTROOT=$SVN_ROOT/bin screen -dm -t "ABC-1234"
SVN_ROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/DEF-5678 OUTPUTROOT=$SVN_ROOT/bin screen -dm -t "DEF-5678"
```

Comment: but this will create 4 screen sessions which is not what I want/need. I need two sessions with both, `OUTPUTROOT` & `SVN_ROOT` set.

Comment: i unfortunately am not able to get it to work the way I want, that's why I've asked the question! I've tried multiple things including: `OUTPUTROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/$1/bin;SVN_ROOT=/home/me/src/NextGen/branches/$1 screen -dm -S $1;` but this does not seem to set `OUTPUTROOT` at all but only `SVN_ROOT` - `$1` being the string I pass to my bash script with the name of the branch/screen session

Comment: so, then... [updated answer]

Comment: `;` always separates two commands, but you were asked for one screen per line. If you wanna use one command, then don't separate them with `;`.

Comment: for me , this solution not worked